# How to deny some path in the nginx / php-fpm config for a symfony API?

Tags: php, rest, symfony, url, nginx

I'm looking for a **simple and safe** way to deny some URLs in a Symfony 3 API deploy on NGINX / PHP-FPM.

Basically, I'd like to allow some urls based on their path.

**Eg. 
/myapi/client/* should be allowed. Anything else should be denied.**

nginx.conf looks like the best option to me. (tell me what you think)

How do you amend the *standard* Symfony 3 NGINX PHP-FPM configuration without breaking the app.php rewriting rule ?

```
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;

    location @rewriteapp {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    # Deny all . files
    location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev)\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_index app.php;
            send_timeout 1800;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;
            fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
      }
```

Comment: If you want to limit access to some endpoints, use symfony security component.
Otherwise, why you put sensitive data in web/public dir?

Comment: I'd like to enable/disable some urls depending on my business needs. it's more a case of availability rather than sensitivity.